# Object unwrap is completely wrong, and weird

Tags: uv

Made this object using cloth physics, converted to mesh,  decimate>unsubdivded it by 2 steps. The first images are what it looks like before unwrapping.

[image: Before UVunwrap photo1]

[image: BeforeUnwrap photo2]

After I mark the seams and unwrap it, everything is wrong. I chose to make the backside of the pillow one cap and the front facing side the other with the sides connected. After the unwrap The small sides dominate the UV space and the mesh inside uvs collapse in on each other. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

[image: seams]

[image]

Comment: Which unwrapping method you are using? From what I see in the screenshot where you placed the seams it should unwrap okay if you simply use the default method with U > _Unwrap_.

Comment: Select the faulty parts and try doing `U` > `Reset` first and then try to unwrap as you wanted to do.

Comment: Hey peeps thank you for the replies, I ended up figuring it out! I forgot that I needed to reset the scale before I unwrapped! In object mode I just needed to hit ctrl+A and select scale. After that my seams and proportions all came out perfect. Anyone know if I need to set this as SOLVED, and how to do it?